# cells are not being colored

Tags: java, colors, apache-poi

so I'm trying to color cells based on some particular value using this function:

```
public static void styleExceptions(CellStyle Exstyle, Font Exfont, Cell cell, AdditiveInformation obj){
    Exfont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
    Exfont.setFontName("Calibri");
    Exstyle.setFont(Exfont);
    Exstyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    Exstyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    Exstyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_DOUBLE);
    Exstyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    Exstyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);

    Object result=null; 
    cellToType(cell,result);

    if(result instanceof Double){

        if((Double)result==obj.get_xmonthreq() || (Double)result==obj.get_xmonthbalance() ||
                (Double)result==obj.get_xmonthendstock()){
                 Exstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
                 Exstyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            }

            else if((Double)result==obj.get_ymonthreq() || (Double)result==obj.get_ymonthbalance() ||
                    (Double)result==obj.get_ymonthendstock()){

                 Exstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_ORANGE.getIndex());
                 Exstyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                 Exstyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_DOUBLE);
            }


            else if((Double)result==obj.get_zmonthreq() || (Double)result==obj.get_zmonthbalance() ||
                    (Double)result==obj.get_zmonthendstock()){

                 Exstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
                 Exstyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                 Exstyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_DOUBLE);
            }
    }

}
```

everything other than the coloring part is working in the function, I'm i doing something wrong with the result object, cause none of the cells that satisfy the conditions are being colored.

this the the cellToType method:

```
private static void cellToType(Cell cell, Object result){

        switch(cell.getCellType()){

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                result= cell.getDateCellValue();
            }
            else
            result=cell.getNumericCellValue();
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
            result=cell.getStringCellValue();
            break; 

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            result=cell.getBooleanCellValue();
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            result=cell.getCellFormula();
            break;  

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of cell");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You had not used `cell.setCellStyle(Exstyle);` anywhere...

After setting the styles, you need to apply the cellstyle on the desired cell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the method:

> cellToType(...)

works as you expects?

I think the problem is that the program doesn't go into the `if` here:

```
Object result=null; 
cellToType(cell,result);
if(result instanceof Double) {
```

Can you post your `cellToType(...)` function?

**EDIT:**
You seems to compare wrongly Double-variables. Instead of `==` try using `result.equalsTo(...)`

Comment: just posted it, you can check it

Comment: isnt that used for strings and objects? not doubles?

Comment: Should be used for all Objects e.g. Double. But also keep in mind that `getNumericCellValue()` returns primitive double, so you are comparing Object vs double.

Comment: but im using the double cast to make the object a primitive double

Comment: No, your cast is `Object->Double` - to Object version of double. Also add extra parenthesis here: `((Double)result)==obj.get_zmonthreq()` cuz I don't know if you are casting `result` or result of `==` operation. (Might be a bug)

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellToStyle` method isn't working because of how you are expecting to change the `result` object in the `styleExceptions` method.  Because Java passes references to objects by value, the `cellToStyle` method receives a copy of the `result` reference in its own `result` parameter.  In that method, you change that local reference, but that does nothing to the `result` reference in `styleExceptions`.

You need to return that reference in `cellToStyle` and assign it to `result` in `styleExceptions`.

```
private static Object cellToType(Cell cell){
    Object result;
    // ...
```

and

```
    return result;
}
```

at the end.  Then, in `styleExceptions`, do this:

```
Object result = cellToType(cell);
```

Comment: ya thanks i realized that yesterday and made the changes yesterday
thanks thoug :)

Comment: but then I pass the the Exstyle  object in a similar way, and i use this (Exstyle) object in the main(), so why does that work, im a little confused now...

Comment: You are manipulating the object referred to by the reference variable `Exstyle` by calling its methods, not assigning a new object to the reference variable.  That is the difference.